# ¿Cómo cambio el core.autocrlf para trabajar con salto de líneas LF en git?

Tags: git, windows

me estoy encontrando un problema con `git` y `Windows`. Resulta que el equipo de trabajo está trabajando en `linux` y yo me encuentro con `Windows`, entonces cuando hago un `commit` los saltos de línea que me toma en cuenta son los `Windows` y por ende las personas de hacer las publicaciones me dice que debo cambiar esto al formato `Linux`.

Buscando en SO Inglés, dice que tan sólo hacer:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

se debería cambiar la configuración, pero, por alguna razón, cuando lo hago me deja en `true`, en otras palabras no veo efecto. 
El código completo:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false

C:\xampp\htdocs\DDDDD\public>git config --list
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
core.edito=atom --wait
core.autocrlf=false
push.default=simple
user.name=Wilfredo Perez
user.email=wilfredo.perez@XXXXXX.com
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.hidedotfiles=dotGitOnly
remote.origin.url=https://bitbucket.org/XXXXX
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Al fin de cuentas, según los docs no se si van en false o input. ¿Alguien me puede orientar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lo que estás viendo son los valores de la configuración local, no global.  La configuración de git puede estar definida en varios puntos, pero toma precedencia la más específica.  Si quieres ver los valores globales tienes que incluir el flag

```
git config --list --global
```

Pero la configuración del repositorio en el que estás trabajando tiene el valor `core.autocrlf=true` y es el que se usará para trabajar en este repositorio.

Por otro lado el valor recomendado si estás trabajando en Windows es dejar `autocrlf` en `true`.  Lo que hace esto es que cuando haces *checkout* al repositorio los cambios de linea serán convertidos a formato Windows (CRLF) pero solo localmente, cuando hagas un *commit* los cambios de linea serán convertidos de vuelta al formato orginal.  Es decir si en el repositorio ya estaba guardada como Windows se queda así, si era Linux (LF) lo convierte.

---

En tu caso específico tienes 2 opciones para cambiar la configuración:

Eliminas el valor de la configuración en el repositorio local de tal manera que se impone el valor global:

```
git config --unset core.autocrlf
```

Cambias el valor local al que quieres, fíjate que aquí no se usa `--global`, solo tienes que ejecutarlo desde la carpeta del repositorio

```
git config core.autocrlf false
```

Comment: Entiendo lo que me dices, revise mi configuración y esta en false. Lo que no entiendo como hacer esto para que me funcione en Windows. Muy capaz y es un problema con el editor de Texto.

Comment: @WilfredoP actualicé la respuesta con tu caso

Comment: Si se cambia la configuración del repositorio, afectaría en futuro a otros usuarios?

Comment: En git tu tienes tu propio repositorio local que no afecta al repositorio remoto, cambiar la configuración solo te afectará a tí

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz y es correcto que esa configuración de `core.autocrlf` aparezca varias veces al momento de hacer git config --list.

Comment: @WilfredoP cuando usas `git config --list` vas a ver todos los valores, de mas general a mas específico, sistema, global y local, en ese order.  El último en aparecer es el valor que "gana".  Sí es normal que aparezcan repetidos.