# Quitar salto de linea Windows para Linux

Tags: linux, git, ssh

He utilizado el comando `git config --global core.autcrlf false` pero me genera el siguiente error:

> Could not lock config file `C:/Program Files/OpenSSH/.gitconfig`: Permission denied.

En español sería:

> No se pudo bloquear el archivo de configuración `C:/Program Files/OpenSSH/.gitconfig`: Permiso denegado.

Comment: ¿Tienes un servidor OpenSSH corriendo o algo así?

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Cómo cambio el core.autocrlf para trabajar con salto de líneas LF en git?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7614/c%C3%B3mo-cambio-el-core-autocrlf-para-trabajar-con-salto-de-l%C3%ADneas-lf-en-git)

Comment: Has probado el comando dos2unix?